# Can an ACTION_MOVE event reach before ACTION_DOWN event in "onInterceptTouchEvent" method of a ViewGroup in an Android application?

Tags: android

I want to initialize an object "obj" for the first event of a gesture.

If ACTION_DOWN always reaches before ACTION_MOVE, I can just initialize the object by checking if current event is ACTION_DOWN.

While, if there is a possibility of ACTION_MOVE reaching before ACTION_DOWN, I'll need to synchronize the initialization of the object on a lock.

Sample code (By using synchronization) is as follows:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    if (object == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (object == null) {
                object = new MyClass();
            }
        }
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_DOWN` is called right after put your finger on the screen.
`ACTION_MOVE` is called when you keep your finger on the screen start moving it.
so technically on `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_DOWN` is being called before.

Comment: Yes, but I want to ask if there is a possibility that ACTION_DOWN is stuck and another event of the same gesture with ACTION_MOVE comes and proceeds in method onInterceptTouchEvent in another thread?

Comment: No. ACTION_DOWN will be called first